# `No transaction in context` error when running a flow

Tags: corda

When running a Corda flow, I receive the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No transaction in context
```

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is likely caused by a failure to annotate a function called from within a flow with the `@Suspendable` annotation. This could either be `FlowLogic.call`, or a function called from within `FlowLogic.call` (e.g. `SignTransactionFlow.checkTransaction` if you are overriding this function as part of a call to `CollectSignaturesFlow`).

If you run flow tests with the following command line flag:

```
-Dco.paralleluniverse.fibers.verifyInstrumentation=true
```

Then the missing annotation will be highlighted if it causes an error. However, this will slow down the running of the tests.