# How to debug quasar error in a corda flow test?

Tags: corda

While running flow unit tests with the MockNetwork for a validating notary, I keep getting flow test failures with ‘Transaction context is missing’ error. I have thoroughly verified there is no method that is missing the `@Suspendable` annotation. On debugging I noticed that the FinalityFlow fails to successfully run the Notary.Client flow, as the latter fails to suspend at the FlowStateMachine. From Stack Overflow, I found an [earlier post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48302454/no-transaction-in-context-error-when-running-a-flow/48302455#48302455) on this error. Adding this flag `-Dco.paralleluniverse.fibers.verifyInstrumentation=true` however, gave me no additional information in the output. I am building my cordapp with corda 4.3 Open Source and using the quasar-0.7.10 jar as recommended in the corda documentation.

Am I missing something here - do I need to change the logging levels? Is the information being sent to a file? How can I correctly instrument the flow test to get more details on the execution?

Here is the exception I see while running my tests.

```
[INFO ] 11:36:28.623 [Mock network] flow. - Flow raised an error: Transaction context is missing. This might happen if a suspendable method is not annotated with @Suspendable annotation.. Sending it to flow hospital to be triaged.
[WARN ] 11:36:28.624 [Mock network] flow. - Caught exception from flow
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Transaction context is missing. This might happen if a suspendable method is not annotated with @Suspendable annotation.
    at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.FlowStateMachineImpl.checkDbTransaction(FlowStateMachineImpl.kt:230) ~[corda-node-4.3.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.FlowStateMachineImpl.processEventImmediately(FlowStateMachineImpl.kt:221) ~[corda-node-4.3.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.FlowStateMachineImpl.run(FlowStateMachineImpl.kt:291) ~[corda-node-4.3.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.FlowStateMachineImpl.run(FlowStateMachineImpl.kt:46) ~[corda-node-4.3.jar:?]
    at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.Fiber.run1(Fiber.java:1092) ~[quasar-core-0.7.10-jdk8.jar:0.7.10]
    at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.Fiber.exec(Fiber.java:788) ~[quasar-core-0.7.10-jdk8.jar:0.7.10]
    at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.RunnableFiberTask.doExec(RunnableFiberTask.java:100) ~[quasar-core-0.7.10-jdk8.jar:0.7.10]
    at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.RunnableFiberTask.run(RunnableFiberTask.java:91) ~[quasar-core-0.7.10-jdk8.jar:0.7.10]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) ~[?:1.8.0_192]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[?:1.8.0_192]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) ~[?:1.8.0_192]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293) ~[?:1.8.0_192]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) ~[?:1.8.0_192]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) ~[?:1.8.0_192]
    at net.corda.node.utilities.AffinityExecutor$ServiceAffinityExecutor$1$thread$1.run(AffinityExecutor.kt:63) ~[corda-node-4.3.jar:?]
```

The MockNetwork is initialized as follows.

```
val testCordapps = cordappPackages.map { TestCordapp.findCordapp(it) }

val mockNetwork = MockNetwork(
    MockNetworkParameters(
        cordappsForAllNodes = testCordapps,
        notarySpecs = listOf(MockNetworkNotarySpec(NOTARY_LEGAL_NAME, validating = true))
    )
)
```

Comment: Can you update your question with the code part where you setup your `MockNetwork`? Also does the error go away if you use a non-validating notary in your test instead of a validating one?

Comment: Hi @AdelRustum,  I have updated the code with the initialization of the MockNetwork. We need to use a validating notary for our use-case, changing to a non-validating one is not really an option. However, for debugging purposes, I will give it a shot and update here.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't forget to add `@Suspendable` to all functions that talk to counter parties? i.e. if a function has a `send` or `receive`, it should be annotated with `@Suspendable`.

Comment: Yes, I have checked my flow(s) several times. In one of the simplest ones - which is a simple exit flow with a single input and no output run at a single node, this very exception still occurs.

Comment: Update: I switched my notary to a non-validating one, and the exception still occurs when the notary is invoked to check for uniqueness.

Comment: I see, well you have two options; either run your flow in debug mode (click debug icon next to function instead of run icon) and put breakpoints, or you can build your nodes and start them locally, but start the node that's throwing the error with a remote debugging configuration; see [enable remote debugging](https://docs.corda.net/docs/corda-os/4.4/node-commandline.html#enabling-remote-debugging)

Comment: I wonder if the quasar library is actually running in your environment. Have you ever succeeded in running an example flow without any FinalityFlow? eg. a flow simply print a line of log and ends it.

Comment: @AdelRustum I have run the flow in debug mode with breakpoints - that's how I know it fails at the Notary.Client flow. I am working on trying to run the flows on nodes in a deployment, to see if the error occurs there too.

Comment: @WayneLam I assume it is, several other flows run successfully with the FinalityFlow. Only some fail with this particular error.

Comment: I ran across the same issue and fixed it by making nullable parameters in a Kotlin function my flow was calling (annotated with @Suspendable) non-nullable.